# Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test as a Measure of Statistical Distance Between Two Dependent Probability Distributions

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Much has been asked on CV regarding the Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test, but not in the context I need.

I'm wondering how feasible it would be to employ KS as a measure of distance between two dependent PDFs, as opposed to using something like the Kullback-Leibler (KL) divergence, cross entropy, or Hellinger distance

Say I partition a distance matrix $D$ into two parts, $A$ and $B$. If I then plot $A$ and $B$ as kernel density estimates, I'd like to know how much their resulting curves overlap (or not). By overlap, I mean the two curves intersect at one or multiple points.

#### Details

In my case, $A$ comprises pairwise distances for a sample of individuals of a particular species, while $B$ contains pairwise distances between individuals for all other species.

So, if I had 3 species in total $\{L, M, N\}$, where I sample 10 individuals of $L$, 3 of $M$, and 2 of $N$, $A$ would contain all  $\binom{10}{2}$ pairwise distances for species $L$, whereas $B$ would contain $\binom{5}{2}$ pairwise distances for individuals of species $M$ and $N$. This scheme would then be repeated for species $M$ and $N$.

Note $A$ and $B$ would not necessarily be conformable, which is a requirement for something like the KL divergence. By conformable, $A$ and $B$ should contain the sample number of elements. At least, that's what I gauge from R when it indicates

```
arrays are non-conformable
```

when I attempt to compute cross entropy.

I could always employ techniques like smoothing to try to get around this, but perhaps there's a simpler way.

I'm thinking the KS test could be used as follows:

$H_0$: $A$ = $B$ (overlap}
$H_1$: $A$ $\neq$ $B$ (separation}

Large values of the test statistic (or small $p$-value) would give strong evidence that the two distributions do not overlap.

Comment: I am struggling with this. What do you mean by “overlap”? How do you create your two groups, and why is there so clearly dependence?

Comment: Now what about the clear dependence? How are you making your groups?

Comment: @Dave I have added details about how the partitions are formed. Please let me know if things are still fuzzy and I will try to clarify.

Comment: Reading your last edit, this seems like a standard “are these distributions equal”-type of problem, for which KS is a classic approach. How do you see your problem as different from other applications of KS? // What do you mean that the groups are not conformable?

Comment: @Dave I've provided more details.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to retain the "array"/matrix structure of a distance matrix when doing this. But don't you actually have two vectors, one of length $\binom{10}{2}$ and one of length $\binom{5}{2}$, in which case the usual KS test is valid?

Comment: @Noah The example with the binomial coefficients is just for illustration. For my actual problem (which contains much more data), $A$ and $B$ are non-conformable matrices (that is, not having the same number of rows as columns). I could coerce to vectors via `as.vector()` but I think that would destroy any structure relating the specimens in my data. Is this what you're getting at? Whether KS is really valid as an alternative distance measure to cross entropy or similar is debatable and is why I ask in this context.

Comment: So you have multivariate distributions?

Comment: @Dave In a sense, yes. At least, once you partition the data in the way described.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you are trying to calculate and how your situation is not amenable to standard methods. You have two distances matrices, $A$, and $B$, each containing a bunch of distances. Based on your description, you want to see if the distributions of the distances differs between $A$ and $B$. What structure are you trying to preserve by not just collapsing the distances into vectors? If you're okay with this, there are many tests for differences of distribution, e.g., energy distance, overlapping coefficient, CVM test, etc. KS seems to be the most popular.

Comment: @Noah Thanks. I think I will look into other tests as well, since for instance, the KS test is more sensitive to area in the centre of distributions, whereas something like the Cramer-Von Mises (CVM) test is more sensitive in the distribution tails. Because no one test rules them all in terms of power, KS may not always be the best choice despite its popularity.

Answer (score 1):

Using the $p$-value is not ideal because it depends on sample size and doesn't estimate anything, but you can use the test statistic. This is just the maximum vertical separation between the CDFs, the uniform/supremum norm on CDFs, which is quite widely studied.